# Invalid format when creating an id_rsa file with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I'm using NodeJS on Ubuntu to generate an `id_rsa` file for ssh. My code looks like this, and the private ssh key is stored in an environment variable called `action.deployKey`.

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from "./util";
import {promisify} from 'util';
import { appendFile } from 'fs';

const action = {
  deployKey: `
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  `
}

const ssh = `${process.env.HOME}/.ssh`;
const createFile = promisify(appendFile)
await createFile(`${ssh}/id_rsa`, action.deployKey)
```

The file appears to be getting created, but I'm running into the following error when I try and run an authenticated request that uses the key.

`Load key "/home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format`

Do I need to set some sort of encoding on this to make the key valid? Or is it possible that the key isn't being written into the file correctly?

The ssh client prints the following before the attempted request gets made so it does appear to have some idea that I added an `id_rsa` file.

`Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address x.x.x.x to the list of known hosts.`

I'm using this within a GitHub action so my only insight is printing the key which I don't want to do.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The file must end with a line break. Is that the case?

Comment: The variable gets stored with a line break, but I'm wondering if Node is removing it?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example - please add an assignment of `action.deployKey` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Done. I've tried a number of things so far but I can't seem to get this to work. Is there a way I can re-format it into the required formatting?

Comment: Did you try removing the leading whitespace before each line, CR/LF before the first `-` of the start marker, and CR/LF and spaces after the last `-` of the end marker?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens in Github Actions when using `OPENSSH` instead of `RSA`

You need to encode the ssh key as an RSA key instead.

```
    -----BEGIN O̶P̶E̶N̶S̶S̶H̶ RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END O̶P̶E̶N̶S̶S̶H̶ RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```